# Drupal 7 Commerce Search API

Tags: api, search, drupal-7, commerce

I would like to create a searchbox like the standard one in Drupal but for Drupal Commerce (1.4). I did not use a product display, but all my products are created.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I found this: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api
and this: http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-search-api (funny english :-) )

I've tried the second one, but I don't need a price ruler. I just want to give the visitor the possibility to search through my products. Not only the title field, but also the description field and if possible the taxonomy terms. It didn't work anyway.

Need help! Thx!

I thought to create this with views, but all good suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score -2):

You could disable the Search API modules and simply use the default Search module provided by Drupal, this would enable searching through nodes, users, etc as usual.

The Search API may be over kill for what you want, unless you have a good mix of variations, prices, product attributes, etc that you would like users to use as search filters (price range, per attribute, etc).